# How to supervise sidekiq and rails server processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, sidekiq

What is the best way to manage multiple interconnected services for a web applications like:

- rails server / unicorn / puma
- redis / sidekiq / resque

So that, if one is stopped or started, others get stopped/started too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a monitoring tool is used for this purpose. One such good tool is [God](http://godrb.com).

The basic idea is to run `God` as a system service, and configure your `sidekiq` to be watched by God. When your server restarts, God runs as a service and it will start your `sidekiq` workers.

You have more benefits by using God, to name just a few:

- notifications: you can configure it to send you notifications when your sidekiq worker dies and gets restarted.
- resource monitoring: you can configure it to take actions based on predefined rules. For example, restart the job when it consumes too much memory.

Update: just read an article this morning which might be very helpful: [Create, run and manage your Ruby background processes with upstart](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/06/create-run-and-manage-your-background-processes-with-upstart/).

Comment: Very helpful James. I read many blogs about God, upstart and Monit. I find people are more complaining about God (i.e. memory leaks) and favoring Monit, though God looks easy and more adaptable for Rails developers.

Comment: My Sidekiq process is also taking huge memory (500-800 MB). I found that some other developers are also complaining this. It seems that ruby programs are prone to memory leakage. What do you think?

Comment: Ghazi, ruby and rails apps are easy to take a lot of memory, but it's not necessary to be leak related. For example, if in your Sidekiq worker it loads a huge amount of activerecord objects it might blow the memory. It's difficult to debug such issues and tweak ruby GC but it's just a reality. You might want to keep each worker small and fast. If a worker does need to operate on a lot of AR objects then carefully tweak the queries and logic (e.g. use `find_each` to batch load db objects to save memory).